# How can I run eval function on my makefile

Tags: makefile, ocaml, eval

I have a makefile to install and compile an ocaml project. I need to install ocaml 4.07 to use some specific features of this version. After installing opam, I download the specific version, but in order to compile the project with this version I get a message from the terminal saying

```
The environment is not in sync with the current switch.
          You should run: eval $(opam env)
```

I want to be able to run `make install` and compile the project in the specific version.

I tried creating an specific rule for the `eval` command to be called and tried also to call both `eval $(opam env)`, `eval 'opam config env'`. But none of these seem to work.

Here is the makefile that I am trying to modify

```
#install package dependencies
install:
    sudo apt install gcc
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:avsm/ppa
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install opam
    opam init --yes
    sudo opam instal ocaml-base-compiler
    #opam init --yes
    sudo apt install ocaml-nox
    #eval 'opam env' 
    #eval $(opam env)
    #ev
    #clear
    #run

# Building the world
run: ev depend $(EXEC)

ev:
    eval $(opam env)

# Clean up
clear:
    rm -f *.cm[io] *.cmx *~ .*~ #*#
    rm -f $(GENERATED)
    rm -f $(EXEC)
```

How can I compile this project with the specific version I downloaded without having to call the `eval` command manually in the terminal, or are there other ways to configure this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice to `eval` something is correct for an interactive shell. Make by default runs each command in a separate shell - it's sort of like you would shut down and restart your computer after each command; the result of `eval` is immediately lost.

There is a GNU `make` extension `.ONESHELL` which allows you to run all lines in a recipe in a single shell, or you can refactor your recipe to do this explicitly:

```
install:
    sudo apt install gcc
    # ... ett etc ...
    opam init --yes \
    && sudo opam instal ocaml-base-compiler
    opam init --yes \
    && sudo apt install ocaml-nox
    eval $(opam env) \
    && ev \
    && run
```

(I had to guess some things about which things need to run in the same shell invocation. I am assuming `ev` and `run` are shell commands which need the `eval`, and that `clear` is the regular shell command which should probably never be used in a Makefile.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `opam config exec ...` to run your build command in the appropriate environment. The build command could be a recursive call to `make`.

But it seems a bit messy to be installing opam inside your `Makefile`. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: in the example `eval $(opam env)` the command is `opam config exec env `?